# C++ textfile reading infinite whileloop

Tags: c++, text-files, infinite-loop, eof

I am doing C++ program which reads infinite while loop,

After letting user enter the desired month and year.
The loop become infinite and only output "AAAAA...."

Textfile(input)

> 1 9 2017|0112233445|20.00 5.00
>  2 9 2017|0123456789|6.00 3.00
>   3 10 2017|0135792468|30.00 1.00
>  4 10 2017|0166778899|7.00
>   10.00
>  4 10 2017|0177001228|40.00 4.00
>  5 10 2017|0184040626|8.00 2.00
>  6 10 2017|0134567892|50.00 6.00
>  7
>   10 2017|0145678910|9.00 7.00

I tried using
 while(inS >> Day>>Month >> Year >> ch >>hpNO >> ch >> c_Charges >> sms_charges )

but nothing seems to be worked .
Any suggestions to solve this problem?Thanks in advance.

```html
void monthlyreport(char manager[])
{
 SYSTEMTIME T;
 GetSystemTime(&T);
 int month, year;   //userinput
 char ch;//store delimitor
 int count = 0;
 

 double Totalcallcharges = 0;
 double Totalsmscharges = 0;
 double Totalcharges = 0;

 int  Day,Month, Year;//for textfile reading
 char hpNO[11];
 double c_Charges =0;
 double sms_charges =0;



 string Months[] = { "January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December" };

 system("cls");
 cout << "You choose : MONTHLY CHARGES REPORT ...";


 cout << "\n\n Which month/year  (mm yyyy)?     ";
 cin >> month;
 cin >> year;



 ifstream inS;
 inS.open("Transaction.txt");
 /*while (inS >> Day)  
 {
  while (inS >> Month)
  {
   while (inS >> Year)
   {
    while (inS >> ch)
    {
     while (inS >> hpNO)
     {
      while (inS >> ch)
      {
       while (inS >> c_Charges)
       {
        while (inS >> sms_charges)
        {
         
          if (month == Month && year == Year)
          {
           Totalcallcharges += c_Charges;
          }
          if (month == Month && year == Year)
          {

           Totalsmscharges += sms_charges;
          }

          count++;
         
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
*/
while (!inS.eof()) correct answer
   {
    inS >> tranS.day >> tranS.month >> tranS.year >> ch;
    inS.getline(tranS.phoneNO, 12, '|');
    inS >> tranS.call_charges >> tranS.sms_charges;


    transactions(&head, tranS);
    if (tranS.month == month &&tranS.year == year)
    {
     tranS.Total_call_charges += tranS.call_charges;
     tranS.Total_sms_charges += tranS.sms_charges;
    }
    count++;
   } 
 Totalcharges = Totalcallcharges + Totalsmscharges;

 inS.close();
 system("cls");

 cout << Month << year;
 cout << endl << c_Charges;
 cout << setw(50) << setfill('=') << " " << endl << endl;
 cout << "       T A R U C M O B I L E   S D N   B H D" << endl << endl;
 cout << setfill(' ') << setw(30) << "Monthly Report - " << Months[month - 1] << " " << year << endl;
 cout << "\nTotal Number of TARUCMOBILE users = " << count;
 cout << "\n\nTotal Charges from Calls = RM" << setw(8) << setfill(' ') << Totalcallcharges << setprecision(2);
 cout << "\nTotal Charges from SMS's = RM" << setw(8) << setfill(' ') << Totalsmscharges << setprecision(2);
 cout << "\n" << setfill(' ') << setw(27) << " " << right << setw(12) << setfill('-') << "-" << endl;
 cout << "TOTAL CHARGES (POSTPAID) = RM" << setw(8) << setfill(' ') << Totalcharges << setprecision(2);
 cout << "\n" << setw(27) << setfill(' ') << " " << setw(12) << setfill('=') << "=" << endl;
 cout << "***        E N D     O F    R E P O R T      *** " << endl << endl;

 cout << "Generated by" << endl;
 cout << "______________" << endl;
 cout << manager << "(Manager)" << endl;
 cout << T.wDay << " " << Months[T.wMonth - 1] << " " << T.wYear << endl;
 cout << endl << setw(50) << setfill('=') << " " << endl;

 
 system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Thanks,but still haven't solve my problem.

Comment: format, remove unnecessary and fixed typo

Comment: What are the typo you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    while(inS >> Day)
    {
    while(inS >> Month)
    {
    while(inS >> Year)
    {
    while(inS >>ch)
    {
    .
    .
    .
    }
```

Then do whatever you want to inside the innermost while loop.

Comment: Finally not infinite loop but it can't read the variable that are in double.It only display '0'.

Comment: I wont write the code for you. Update your post so I can see your new code.

Comment: Why does you file have '|' ? Seems to me that could cause your problem.

Comment: using inS.getline(phoneNO, 12, '|') solve my problem.Thanks for the help.